# MD5 Hash different on local machines

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I have an MD5 hash method like so:

```
MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        lock (md5)
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2").ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
```

On several local dev machines using the same input, this returns the same hash. On staging and live servers too, it is returnging the expected value.

However, on a few local development machines the values differ. And I cannot figure out why?

I added the `lock` and the `CultureInfo` in response to some other answers on here.. but alas. Nothing.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated in this matter!

**UPDATE:**

I have gotten to the point where I compared the inputBytes array on a 'good' vs. a 'bad' machine and the arrays are identical.

So what, if anything, could the ComputeHash method be doing differently between machines? I feel like that isn't the underlying issue.. but at this point that is where the hash comes back different. I am at a loss.

Comment: are you 100% sure your input is the same ? I know it's an annoying question, but it would be the first thing I check if I had this issue

Comment: Agree with @Bartdude.  Also perhaps Big/little endian?  OS difference?  Virus scanner modification?  Take the file from a "bad machine" and copy it back to one of the matching machines.  See what happens.

Comment: Like @Bartdude, I'm also suspicious about the input. Double-check that the input always has the same encoding and so on across all machines. Whether or not the method itself is culture invariant is irrelevant if the input doesn't match.

Comment: Well, yes I am 100% sure. I have stepped through the debugger and watched the input string on all the 'bad machines'. It is always the same. 
The OS's are the same version, but I guess when it comes down to it, I am not sure all the variables that come into play when creating an MD5 hash. 
I will try to move the dll from a 'bad machine' to a 'good' one and see what the result is.

Comment: Well @Bartdude. You were right. Turns out the input had a datetime in it that was pulling from system time. The strings differed ever so slightly that I didn't see it. And as annoying as that question actually was.. I'm glad you asked it. Thanks very much!

Comment: When it comes to compare files, I use a compare tool which highlight any differences. I use Araxis Merge, but there are a lot of others out there. May be of use in some cases. And always remember : the simpler explanation is most of the time the best one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @bartdude the input was different on either machine due to a datetime variable that was pulling from different system time formats.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.